# How to pin cloth to another mesh without an armature

Tags: cloth-simulation

I've been messing around with some simple skirt models and I was wondering how I could pin the cloth so that when the mesh moves the cloth stays with the mesh.

I currently have a skirt draped over a mannequin without an armature and when I make the mannequin spin the skirt slides around her waist instead of moving along with it.

As a visual I made a red stripe on the mannequin and the skirt. After 1 spin and a half the skirt only does almost a full spin.

[image: Test Visual]

Comment: Looks great. Is it a circle shape at the beginning? -- If you define a pin group you can rotate the skirt mesh with keyframes or just parent it to the mannequin. For the pin group: create a vertex group, assign the top vertices of the skirt to it, then use this vertex group in the cloth settings *Shape > Pin Group*

Comment: @Blunder The shape I used was a cylinder, after some testing I figured out that it was not possible to have the same type of pin on a cylinder instead of a plane. When I used the plane it worked but the outcome was not nearly the same as I hoped

Answer (score 0):

As Blunder said, if the meshes are separate, you can parent the skirt to the mannequin. That way, when the mannequin moves, the pinned, not-simulated-cloth parts of the skirt should move with the mannequin, the same way that armatures work, but not with armatures.

Comment: Is there a way that a cylinder can be pinned to the mannequin instead of a plane?

Comment: What do you mean? You can pin any vertex groups on any mesh, and the pinned vertices won't be simulated, which means that they'll move with parented objects.